# How to use regex to replace a specific group in a string using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I want to read in a string and delete the captured group (in this case "[^ ]+(&)[^ ]).

```
x = "apple&bob & john & smith" # original string
x = "applebob & john & smith" #after replacing string
```

This is the code I am using now.

```
import re

and_regex = re.compile(r'([^ ]+(&)[^ ])')
x = "apple&bob & john & smith"
x = re.sub(and_regex, " ",x)
print(x)
```

I cannot use the string replace (string.replace) because it will replace the "&"s in the entire string.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I wonder if lookarounds would be helpful here: `re.compile(r'(?<=\S)&(?=\S)')`.

Comment: What is the expected for `&apple&bob & john & smith&` ?

Answer (score 3):

you can do this:

```
import re
x = "apple&bob & john & smith"
x = re.sub("(?<=\S)&(?=\S)", "",x)
print(x)
```

output:

```
applebob & john & smith
```

Comment: Exactly the complement to my method ;) . Lookarounds I have always to lookup anew. So I prefer a method without lookarounds. (lazier ;) ).

Comment: As one can see - without lookarounds, one has to repeatedly apply `re.sub()` to replace all occurrences of matches, with lookarounds only once - so this solution is more elegant in the hindsight!

Answer (score 2):

As al alternative, if you also want to remove the `&` char at the start and end in for example `&apple&bob & john & smith&` you can either assert a non whitespace char to the left OR assert a non whitespace char to the right.

```
(?<=\S)&|&(?=\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/64DMKm/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "apple&bob & john & smith",
    "&apple&bob & john & smith&",
    "&apple&bob & john & smith&&"
]

for s in strings:
    print(re.sub(r"(?<=\S)&|&(?=\S)", "", s))
```

Output

```
applebob & john & smith
applebob & john & smith
applebob & john & smith
```

Comment: That is the most sophisticate pattern!

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim Thanks, it is an alternative in case having 2 non whitespace chars at the left and right is not required.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture those parts you want to keep.
And when replacing with `.sub()` method, enter the
captures parts using `\\1` and `\\2` in the replacer string.

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\S+)&(\S+)')
# `\S` means: any non-white character.
# see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

x = "apple&bob & john & smith"
x = pattern.sub("\\1\\2", x) # or also: re.sub(pattern, "\\1\\2", x)

x
## 'applebob & john & smith'
```

However, this replaces only 1 occurrence, the leftmost non-overlapping one, we need a function to replace all occurrences in the string. One can solve it using recursion:

```
def replace_all_pattern(pattern, s):
    if bool(re.match(pattern, s)):
        res = re.sub(pattern, "\\1\\2", s)
        return replace_all_pattern(pattern, res)
    else:
        return s


replace_all_pattern(r"(\S+)&(\S+)", "abble&bob&john&smith")
## 'abblebobjohnsmith'
```

But this will be performance-wise less efficient than using look-arounds. So use this only if exactly one occurrence is to be replaced. In that case, preformance-wise, it is better than the look-arounds, but as soon as more than one occurrences are possible and have to be checked: use the look-arounds as pattern, because they will be more efficient.

Comment: This solution does not works with "apple&bob&john&smith": it gives "apple&bob&johnsmith".

Comment: ah I see ... it does it only once and not repeatedly.

Comment: but it is a problem of `re.sub()`: "Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
replacement repl."

Comment: So we have to write a more sophisticated function to replace all occurrences.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is in "non-overlapping". I think you need at least one look-around. If you put a look-around on the right it should be better than 2 look-around because they are costly (possibly done with non-linear parsing), especially look-ahead.

Comment: Ah I see, with lookaround it works! - okay point for your version, @JérômeRichard ! It is more elegant.

Comment: Yes, with them, it gives "applebobjohnsmith" because look-around are not greedy (this is what makes them inefficient but also avoid the overlapping issue)

Comment: Interesting! Learned something! Thank you a lot pointing that out! It is also important to keep in behind the efficiency point with the look-arounds. But I guess they are still more efficient than my recursive solution, because you have to check with `.match()` first and then `.sub()` it then call function again etc.